# UITableView inside UIPageViewController EdgeInset issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a containing `UIViewController` that conforms to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and has a `UIPageViewController` as a `childViewController`. The container then appropriately loads other `ViewControllers` into the PageView as its the datasource. Everything works fine except for one small caveat. One of the ViewControllers loaded by the container is a `UITableViewController`. This `UITableView` seems to have no `insets` set. I'm not sure why not other than perhaps an issue with PVC not attaining the correct insets from the container. The `UIPageViewController` definitely has `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, however, even if I set this to false and do it manually in the storyBoard, it still doesn't work.

I'm using Swift for this project and AutoLayout is on, but not in the .xib for the `UITableViewController`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Mike

Comment: what did work for me was setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true for the affected components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known "feature" of `UITableViewController`. It grabs the entire root view so that the insets will be ignored.

The solution is to use a `UIViewController` that has a table view and conforms to its datasource and delegate.

Comment: I actually initially started off with a UIViewController and a UITableView inside it, but when that didn't work I switched it to a UITableViewController but sadly it still didn't fix it.

Comment: Did you set the insets?

Comment: On the ViewController with the TableView? I will have done but I can change it again, to test it.

Comment: Yup it worked, set the insets manually to 64 in the storyboard with the UITableView nested inside a UIViewController. Must have overridden it somewhere before when it didn't work. Thanks.